# Geometry equivalence between Giant Contend 2 and Fuji Feather

Tags: frames, size, geometry, giant

I have been using a Giant Contend 2 for over 2 years and I am really comfortable with its geometry.

Now, I want to purchase online a Fuji Feather, with a similar fit, but I got a bit confused with their size recommendations.

The Giant Contend 2 size I am using is 535 (ML), which has 560mm top tube length. When I compare that with the Feather sizes, it corresponds to somewhere in L. The confusing part is that Giant recommends 535 (ML) for riders between 180~190cm, while Fuji recommends L for up to 180cm.

I am not an expert on bike geometries, but my guess is that I shouldn't decide the equivalent geometry based on the top tube alone, probably because the Feather has a more vintage geometry.

What other measurements should I be looking at? How can I select a size for the Feather that has a similar fit to the Contend 2?

The geometry for the Feather 2021 and 2022 is different, but I have no preference over the model year.

My height is 186cm.

## Geometry charts

#### Giant Contend 2 2021

[image]
Source: https://www.giant.co.jp/giant20/bike_datail.php?p_id=00000207#geometry

#### Fuji Feather 2021

[image]
Source: https://www.fujibikes.com/usa/bikes/pavement/urban/feather/feather-2021

#### Fuji Feather 2022

[image]
Source: https://www.fujibikes.com/usa/bikes/pavement/urban/feather/feather

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool such as the one I've linked here to compare the two bikes and different sizes.

https://bikeinsights.com/compare?geometries=5eddcf7abcf4aa00170cfad6,5ea1a0ac62942c001798523b,

The main glaring difference I can see (the sizes of the two bikes you refer to are in many ways very similar) is that the Contend has a very high stack and allows for a much higher handlebar position. Really you need to know that the low stack position of the feather is going to suit your goals, while handlebar reach should be easy to configure with a replacement stem.

You will not be able to reproduce the bike fit (bar height) of the contend on the feather so unless your bars are slammed and you still want to go lower, bear that in mind.

__

I appreciate that the feather in my link is a bit older but the head tube measurements in your geometry charts all tell a similar story